# Relation between two homomorphisms from $SO(3)$ to the Möbius group $PGL(2,\mathbb{C})$

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-groups

Let $f, g$ be two homomorphisms from $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ to $PGL(2,\mathbb{C})$. Does there exist $S \in \mathrm{PGL}(2,\mathbb{C})$ such that for all $X\in \mathrm{SO}(3)$ we have $g(X)=Sf(X)S^{-1}$?

Background: I have images which are stereographic projections of subparts of a sphere. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation) the images transform into each other using Möbius transforms. I want to parametrize these transforms in terms of the rotations given by the actuator. If the above is true the parametrization would be quite simple: i can pick any homomorphism and then just need to parametrize $S$.

Comment: If you don't specify continuous homomorphism, then this is false, since the automorphism group of $PGL_2(\mathbb{C})$ contains $Gal(\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Q})$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two continuous group morphisms $SO_3\to PSL_2\mathbb{C}$ up to conjugacy: the obvious one as rotations of the Riemann sphere, and the trivial one with image the identity element. The proof: We see from the Lie algebra of $SO_3$ (cross product of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$) that $SO_3$ has simple Lie algebra. Hence the image $G$ of any morphism is a 0-dimensional or a 3-dimensional compact and connected group. If 0-dimensional, it is the identity element, because it is connected. So suppose that $G$ is 3-dimensional.

By $QR$ decomposition, $PSL_2\mathbb{C}$ retracts to $SO_3$, so $SO_3$ is a maximal compact subgroup, and is connected. All maximal compact subgroups are conjugate. So any maximal compact subgroup containing $G$ is a conjugate of $SO_3$. By dimension count, and connectivity, $G$ is a maximal compact subgroup, so a conjugate of $SO_3$, so unique up to conjugacy. We thus reduce to the problem of proving that $SO_3$ automorphisms are inner, which is clear from its Dynkin diagram, as it is rank one, so has a Dynkin diagram with only one node, hence no noninner automorphisms.

Comment: A much simpler linear algebra proof is probably not hard to cook up.

Comment: I have no idea what's meant by "hence no nontrivial automorphisms", since the Dynkin argument directly says the fact about the outer automorphism group (while of course there are nontrivial automorphisms, namely inner).

Comment: Why does the image have to be maximal compact? The image of the trivial homomorphism is not maximally compact

Comment: @SebastianSchulz, thanks for asking this!  Certainly the argument meant to include the caveat 'non-trivial' on the morphism, but even then I can't see it.  A non-trivial morphism from $\operatorname{SO}_3(\mathbb R)$ will have image isomorphic either to $\operatorname{SO}_3(\mathbb R)$ or its adjoint quotient, but is it obvious that the only way to embed either of those in $\operatorname{PSL}_2(\mathbb C)$ is as a maximal compact subgroup?

Comment: @LSpice for reasons of dimension. If $SO_3$ or its adjoint quotient is embedded, the image's dimension is the dimension of a maximal compact. The image is compact, so it must be maximal.

Comment: @JoshuaMundinger, but, still, connected components...? Some details...

Comment: @LSpice what you mean by "its adjoint quotient"? $\mathrm{SO}_3$ is its own adjoint quotient; it's abstractly a simple group. The whole thing is clear. If the (continuous) homomorphism is nontrivial, its image is 3-dimensional, compact, and since the maximal compact subgroups in $\mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbf{C})$ are 3-dimensional and connected [the maximal compact subgroups of every connected Lie group are connected!], the image is maximal compact.

Comment: @YCor, I always mix up which SO's have centres.  As to "the whole thing is clear", well, it wasn't to me, which is why I asked; but now it is, because you explained it clearly.  (I didn't know that maximal compacts in the real setting are connected; it's not always true in the $p$-adic setting.)

Comment: @LSpice actually if $G$ is a connected Lie group with finitely many components and $K$ a maximal compact subgroup, then the inclusion $K\to G$ is a homotopy equivalence and $G$ is homeomorphic to $K\times G/K$, with $G/K$ homeomorphic to a Euclidean space; in particular $G$ is connected iff $K$ is connected. In the $p$-adic case only $\{1\}$ is connected...

Comment: @YCor, in the $p$-adic case we have the Bruhat–Tits-type scheme-theoretic models of certain compact subgroups, and it makes sense to talk about whether those underlying schemes are connected.  (More prosaically, we are dealing with pro-Lie groups over finite fields, and one may ask whether the "top" quotient is the group of rational points of a connected algebraic group.)  This is in the same slightly abusive spirit as that in which one refers to a connected $p$-adic Lie group.  But, of course, that is afield of this question.

Answer (score 6):

Any continuous homomorphism $SO_3 \to SL_2(\mathbb C)$ is trivial because $SO_3$ is compact and has only one irreducible representation of dimension at most two: the trivial representation.

**EDIT:** the revised question may still be answered by representation theory. A continuous homomorphism $f: SO_3 \to PGL_2(\mathbb C)$ has a unique lift to a homomorphism $\tilde f: SU_2 \to SL_2(\mathbb C)$. By the representation theory of $SU_2$, there are two representations of dimension two: the trivial representation and the defining representation on $\mathbb C^2$. Thus if $f,g: SO_3 \to PGL_2(\mathbb C)$ are both nontrivial and continuous, their lifts $\tilde f, \tilde g$ are conjugate and thus $f$ and $g$ are conjugate.

Comment: I had to change $SL$ to the Möbius group, sry. The special unitary subgroup is isomorphic to SO(3). Hence there are nontrivial homomorphisms. Furthermore by taking any $S$ and doing the transformation as above we can make new homomorphisms. The question is then if we can create all of them that way.

Comment: (Note: this addressed an early wrong version of the question). Here's an immediate proof that the only homomorphism $f$ [not assumed continuous] $\mathrm{SO}(3)\to\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{C})$ is trivial. Since the only elements of order dividing $2$ in $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{C})$ are $\pm I$, all elements of order $2$ in $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ map into $\pm 1$. Since $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ is generated by its elements of order $2$, $f$ maps into $\{\pm 1\}$. Since moreover these elements of order 2 are commutators, everything maps to $1$. (I'm not even using abstract simplicity of $\mathrm{SO}(3)$.)